# Newsletter containing images - images have space between them on mobile

Tags: html, css, image

I send newsletters from my Drupal-7 website using Simplenews newsletter module. The newsletters are basic HTML and CSS, and always contain small images, that when added side by side, they create a bigger image.
The newsletter appears fine when you receive it at any browser, but when you receive it on mobile, the images have a big space between them. What should I add in order to fix that?
Here is the code that I already use. It is the table-code generated when you crop the full-image on slices and I made a few css changes:

```
<table id="Table_01" width="750" height="1636" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <a href="link" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.png" width="750" height="319" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <a href="link" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.png" width="750" height="336" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <a href="link" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.png" width="750" height="702" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <a href="link" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.png" width="750" height="71" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <a href="link" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.png" width="750" height="46" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="test" width="750" height="28" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.png" width="422" height="44" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="link" target="_blank"> 
        <img src="test.png" width="29" height="44" alt="" style="display:block;">
        </a>
        </td>
    <td>
        <a href="link" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.png" width="299" height="44" alt="" style="display:block;">
        </a>
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="link" width="750" height="90" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! What it needed, is to add some spacer.gif images, whom width adds to the total width if the table created.
For example:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="272" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="12" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="6" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="233" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="37" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="35" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="12" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="67" height="1">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="286" height="1">
</td>
```